# Which python re module to pick for translating a perl regular expression

Tags: python, perl

I have the perl regular expression `/VA=\d+:(\S+):ENSG/` which is used in a if statement as

```
if ($info =~ /VA=\d+:(\S+):ENSG/){
    $gene =$1;
```

I am trying to figure out what the best way to replicate this in python would be. Right now I have

```
gene_re = re.compile(r'VA=\d+:(\S+):ENSG')
this_re = re.search(gene_re, info)
if this_re is not None:
    gene = info[this_re.start(0):this_re.end(0)]
```

Is this a good way to translate it? I guess this is one area where perl is actually more readable than python.

Note that the python regular expression is compiled because the next three lines are actually inside a loop.

Comment: No need for `if this_re is not None` there.  In python one would typically just say `if this_re:`.

Comment: I was taught to use is not None because it is more legible and because None != False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
gene = this_re.group(1)
```

instead of

```
gene = info[this_re.start(0):this_re.end(0)]
```

---

By the way, the Python `re` module caches the `N` most recently used regex patterns, so (unless you have a very large number of patterns)  it is not necessary to pre-compile it.

For Python 2.7, `re._MAXCACHE` (i.e. `N`) is 100.

Comment: I did not know that about the re caching that is very cool. One question - shouldn't it be group(0) not group(1)?

Comment: Even though Python uses 0-based indexing, the regex groups are numbered starting with 1. So it is `group(1)`. This is consistent with `r'\1'` referring to the group 1 match when using `re.sub`.

Comment: From the interpreter: >>> p = re.match('a','aa')
>>> p.group(0)
'a'

Comment: If `p = re.match('(a)(b)', 'ab')`, then `p.group(0)` is `'ab'`, while `p.group(1)` is `a`. You want `p.group(1)`. `group(0)` is the entire match, `group(1)` is the first parenthesized match. See [re.group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).